# Insert Variable based on an ID

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-into

I want to use an INSERT query to insert multiple rows (100's) based on which ID's aren't in Table B but are in Table A.  This i have managed to do, and most of the information that needs to be inserted i got sorted out except for one. This value is a value found in Table A that is different for each ID.

How can i insert correct corresponding Value from A to B based on where the ID's are the same?
The **Simplified** tables:

```
TableA                            TableB
ID    |Value                      ID    | Value   | Other | Other
--------------                   ---------------------------------
1     | ABC                       1     | ABC     | ****  | ****
2     | DFG                       2     | DFG     | ****  | ****
3     | HBO                       3     | HBO     | ****  | ****
```

I tried using this query:

```
    INSERT INTO TableB
(
    ID,
    Value, 
    Other, 
    Other
)
SELECT 
    ID, 
    (SELECT TABLEA.Value FROM TABLEA,TABLEB WHERE TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID),
    ******, 
    ******

FROM TableA
WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT 
        TABLEA.ID
    FROM
        TABLEA

    MINUS

    SELECT 
        TABLEB.ID 
    FROM
        TABLEB
)
```

But obviously the problem with this is that it compares all ID's not the single one i need. Are there any solutions to do this inside the insert? Or do i need to insert first, leaving this value empty,  and then use an UPDATE query  to give it the correct value?

EDIT:
Altough the problem mentioned is solved i stil have some other issues that are related. 
The following query is what is currently in the works:

```
MERGE INTO  TableB
USING   TableA
ON      (TableB.id = TableA.id) 
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
            SET TableB.VALUE = TableA.VALUE
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT 
        (
            id, 
            POSITION,  
            other,    
            other, 
            other,   
            other, 
            other,
            VALUE
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            TableA.id,
            (
                SELECT POSITION
                FROM TableC
                WHERE something = '<String Value>'
                AND VALUE = 
                (
                    SELECT VALUE 
                    FROM TableA 
                    WHERE TableA.id = <The Current 'ID'> 
                ) , 
            )
            *****,    
            *****, 
            *****,    
            *****, 
            *****, 
            TableA.VALUE
        );
```

With the main question being, how can i get "Value" from the correct row so i am able to get the correct "POSITION".

Comment: what do you mean by *This value is a value found in Table A that is different for each ID.*

Comment: Table A has a large number of id's each ID has values connected to them which can be different for each ID. (So people won't assume the value is always the same and suggest things like just inserting the value manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF I understand it correctly, you want to insert in TableB those rows from TableA that have ID's not present in TableB. For ID's present in TableB you want to update their values with values from TableA. Right?

If that is true, you want to use MERGE statement. Answer is similar to the one previous user posted, but corrected and this one should work fine:

```
MERGE INTO TABLEB tgt
USING TABLEA src
    ON (tgt.ID = src.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED
   THEN
       UPDATE
       SET tgt.value = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT (
            ID
            ,VALUE
            )
        VALUES (
            src.id
           ,src.value
           );
```

Answer to the additional question:

```
MERGE INTO  TableB
USING   TableA
ON      (TableB.id = TableA.id) 
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
            SET TableB.VALUE = TableA.VALUE
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT 
        (
            id, 
            POSITION,  
            other,    
            other, 
            other,   
            other, 
            other,
            VALUE
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            TableA.id,
            (
                SELECT POSITION
                FROM TableC
                    WHERE something = '<String Value>'
                AND VALUE = TableA.VALUE
            ) as position,
            *****,    
            *****, 
            *****,    
            *****, 
            *****, 
            TableA.VALUE
        );
```

Additionally, if you would want to merge tables only for ID's that are between 1200 and 1299 (as stated in the comments to my answer), try writing the code like this:

```
MERGE INTO  (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE ID BETWEEN 1200 AND 1299) TableB 
USING   (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID BETWEEN 1200 AND 1299) TableA 
ON      (TableB.id = TableA.id) 
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
            SET TableB.VALUE = TableA.VALUE
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT 
        (
            id, 
            POSITION,  
            other,    
            other, 
            other,   
            other, 
            other,
            VALUE
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            TableA.id,
            (
                SELECT POSITION
                FROM TableC
                    WHERE something = '<String Value>'
                AND VALUE = TableA.VALUE
            ) as position,
            *****,    
            *****, 
            *****,    
            *****, 
            *****, 
            TableA.VALUE
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the mistake, but for a small typo, a simple comment would have sufficed rather than posting the same answer. You may write a different query though if it adds any value.

Comment: It is more then a typo, it contains two mistakes (plural) and it does a different thing.

Comment: The only similarity actually is utilizing MERGE statement (which is obvious with OPs' needs), once in a way that it does what OP is asking, and once in a way that is not doing it (not mentioning that mistakes in MERGE can be very dangerous, as I believe you already know).

Comment: You noticed a mistake, that's a good thing. I agree that it wasn't just a typo but not an intentional mistake and more of an editing error. The similarity is more than just using MERGE statement, it has same aliases, upper/lowercase and the formatting. I don't have a problem with you posting the correct answer on your own. But, pasting the same is not something which I would have done myself.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: O sorry i accidentally edited in the wrong section , my apologies i am rather new here. I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: Of course, I copy-pasted your MERGE structure, because that skeleton is mandatory for every MERGE statement. It was easier and faster than writing every letter of the statement from scratch. Perhaps I could've copied it from official Oracle documentation. OK. But why? The mandatory structure was here and then I wrote the editable parts in a way that it agrees with OPs' needs. 
Had I known that it would bother you or anyone else, I would've named the tables 'tab1' and 'tab2', respectively (although I don't like that nomenclature).
Tnx for input, in future I might do so. It seems it matters.

Comment: @A.Bakker please see if my answer to your additional question helped you.

Comment: @GoranKutlaca

I get this:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (TABLEB"."POSITION")

There are no null's in the database so this shouldn't be possible

Comment: @A.Bakker does your TableC has any value for that something = '<String Value>' and value = TableA.value ? 
If not, you have to decide if you would either make it possible to insert null in TableB.position , or have a value that would be inserted instead of null, when there is no according data in TableC

Comment: @GoranKutlaca 
The error is resolved when i add Table A to the from in the values section. 
But then i get the problem that it returns all the matches, not the one of the insert currently being done.

Comment: @A.Bakker Does your TableC has any value for that something = '<String Value>' and value = TableA.value ?
Can you clarify what do you want to happen when there is no such data in TableC?

Comment: @GoranKutlaca , i think i found the problem. 
first time suing the Merge, and i forgot something. I need to filter the ID's and only take the ID's that start with the number "12"  soo only 1200 to 1299. 
Where in a merge should i place this WHERE statement? Then it should never return a null value.

Comment: @GoranKutlaca It seems a college of mine has been inconsistent with certain values... i'll first have to sort that out before i can test this properly. 

thanks for the help and i'll give a sign if it's fixed.

Comment: @A.Bakker I added the where statements in my answer. Try it and see if it helps.
Also, please adjust your question so that my answer remains relevant for anyone who looks at it in the future.
If you'll have additional questions or changes to the request, please rate this answer and close it, so to keep relevance of other answers as well. Than open another question if you wish, with that changed inquiry, where I will try to help you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `MERGE`  statement.

```
MERGE INTO TABLEB tgt
USING TABLEA src
    ON (tgt.ID = src.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET tgt.value = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT (
            ID
            ,VALUE
            )
        VALUES (
            src.id
            ,src.value
            );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe94d)

Comment: It works for this, but was hoping i could also use it for a different problem that is a bit harder to explain haha. Sadly i can't use this code for that. 
Something that i need is like a Variable that i can use in a sub-query with the variable being the ID of the row that is getting inserted :/

Comment: @A.Bakker : You seem to be confused about accepting the right answer. I personally don't mind you accepting any answer as long as it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing it has been edited based on the comments of the other post i thought it would be possible to mark both answers as correct. My bad. still new here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : -

```
    INSERT INTO B 
       SELECT A.id, A.value  
         FROM A 
         FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.id IS NULL
```